# Awk replace string where specific condition is true using variables

Tags: awk, scripting

I am trying to replace a string where a specific condition is true in the same line using awk variables.

I found something that could help me a lot but I'm facing a new challenge cause a I need to do this using variables.

Here an example of my content file.

```
0;20220808163547;
1224;20220808163547;
1224;20220808170514;
0;20220808170514;
```

I need always to replace the first column when the second column match the value `20220808170514`.

Thanks to other post I could accomplish it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664446/bash-replace-string-where-specific-condition-is-true

This works fine.

```
awk '/20220808170514/ {sub(/0/,"2048")}1' FileName.ctrl
```

But I need to do this in a dynamic way.

```
v1=2048
v2=20220808170514
awk -v var1="$v1" -v var2="$v2" '/var2/ {sub(/0;/,var1";")}1' FileName.ctrl
```

But it didnt work.

```
0;20220808163547;
0;20220808163547;
0;20220808170514;
0;20220808170514;
```

I need something like this

```
0;20220808163547;
1224;20220808163547;
2048;20220808170514;
2048;20220808170514;
```

PS: v1 and v2 it'll be different among the time.

Comment: See "Example of testing the contents of a shell variable as a regexp:" in the accepted answer at [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this:

```
$ awk -v FS=';' -v OFS=';' -v var1="$v1" -v var2="$v2" '$2 == var2 { $1 = var1 } 1' filename 
0;20220808163547;
1224;20220808163547;
2048;20220808170514;
2048;20220808170514;
```

First, the way to match the line against a pattern in a variable would be `$0 ~ var`. Just `/var/` would take that as a literal regex. Then, `sub(/0;/, ...)` would only replace the first field if it's `0`, it wouldn't replace `1224`.

But if we set the field separators correctly, we can just if the second field (`$2`) is identical to the value in the variable, and then we can just replace the first field (`$1`). It requires setting the input and output field separators (`FS` and `OFS`) to the `;` used in your file.